# Android Nested Api Calling using Retrofit 2.0 Java

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

first API @GET http://baseURL/product response me a list of product id

```
 [
 {
 "product_uuid": "17e0a97e-66d1-4ba6-88e1-9d72cffaf20d",
 "short_name": "10 pcs Fried Chicken",
 },
{
 "product_uuid": "290174c3-65e3-4852-9494-fcd039b0fa16",
 "short_name": "Fried Chicken",
 },
]
```

but i have to call again http://baseurl/product/{product_id}  to get details information for all product of the list...
how can i call details api from first api

Comment: You should use rxjava and disposables requests

Answer (score 0):

**Its My Personal suggestion for easy use**

if you do not want to use Rxjava then you have to call firstApi After get successfully response then quickly call second api like if productId not null or Response data is notnull then call second api...

**NextLevel Gurrenty Work**

You have to use WorkManager android for this kind of sequence Work Because they are gurrenty that work is doing...